# XPath Get Upper Node Value With Provided Lower Node Value

Tags: xml, xpath

I have node values where SData Event is different between the 2 elements below and need to return the Event value "WK1" when only providing the FormData "PEMD" and ItemData "2019-12-18"
I can't provide the Subject value as this will not be known, only ItemData Value.

```
<Data>
<Data1 Study="R1979" MetaDataVersionOID="6713">
    <Data2 Subject="4100">
        <SData Event="SCN" key="WK1[1]">
            <FormData Form="PEMD" FormKey="1">
                <ItemData Item="PM" Value="1"/>
                <ItemData Item="PE" Value="1"/>
                <ItemData Item="DATE" Value="2020-01-01"/>
            </FormData>
        </SData>
    </Data2>
</Data1>
<Data1 Study="R1979" MetaDataVersionOID="6713">
    <Data2 Subject="4200">
        <SData Event="WK1" key="WK1[1]">
        <FormData Form="PEMD" Formkey="1">
        <ItemData Item="PM" Value="1"/>
        <ItemData Item="PE" Value="1"/>
        <ItemData Item="DATE" Value="2019-12-18"/>
        </FormData>
        </SData>
    </Data2>
</Data1>
```

I have tried

```
/Data/Data1/Data2/SData[@Event]/FormData[@Form='PEMD']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//SData[FormData[@Form="PEMD"]/ItemData[@Item="DATE"]/@Value="2019-12-18"]/@Event
```

will return the `Event="WK1"` attribute as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative :

```
//FormData[@Form="PEMD"][./ItemData[@Value="2019-12-18"]]/../@Event
```

Look for a `FormData` element with specific attribute (attribute : `PEMD`) and a specific `ItemData` child (attribute : `2019-12-18`). Then get the attribute (`@Event`) of the parent element (`..`).

Output : `WK1`